# Is IDE integration *really* useful for a DVCS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, mercurial, dvcs

Specifically, for Visual Studio 2008 (or 2010) and Mercurial, but generalize if desired.

Comment: is there any difference of mechanism between ide integration for centralized vcs versus dvcs

Comment: @Midhat - I don't know about DVCS vs. centralized, but some source control systems *do* have a bigger need for integration (for example, in any system where you need to explicitly check out a file, integration is practically a must).

Comment: Yes, @Midhat, that was the point of my question.  In my experience (20 years on Sourcesafe) files are read-only unless checked out, and that would really suck if not integrated.

Comment: but svn is centralized and you dont need to "check-out" files like sourcesafe to work on them. (yes there is a checkout command in svn but that has a different semantic). So does SVN integration is different from mercurial integration

Comment: and personally i prefer my version control seperate from the ide

Comment: @Jerry - Clearcase works the same way (at least in my experience), where a file will be read-only until checked out. I agree that in this kind of environment, you *need* your VCS integrated into your IDE to be productive.

Comment: Update: I installed visual svn and its useful for a quick revert if I made any temp changes to a file for testing. Otherwise I would stick to my Check for Modifications -> Update -> Commit cycle

Answer (score 2):

While I don't use Visual Studio, I have used *many* IDEs over the years and never felt that any version control integration was truly worth the time and effort.  I have always felt more comfortable managing my version control from the command line as opposed to *any* GUI, integrated or otherwise.

Comment: Yes I also feel teh same way, but I think its just a matter of personal preference

Comment: I almost agree. I don't really care if there is a CLI or a GUI client (TortoiseSVN is great) - *JUST KEEP IT OUT OF MY IDE.* Why? Because the years of development and debugging that have gone into the original clients makes the hacked IDE "integration" look like a joke.

Answer (score 1):

IDE integration is always nice; that way you can conveniently check in changes as you make (and test) them, which encourages you to check in early and often.

Answer (score 1):

For a start it *is* undoubtly useful for people who are commandline-phobic.

Then it depends how confident you are at the command line and how powerful your command line "shell" is. I'm working on a 200KLOC project that was switched quite some time ago from SVN to Mercurial.

I'm doing everything from the command line: I've got shells one shortcut away from my IDE and when I'm in a directory with a Mercurial repository I get a nice custom command prompt showing me the number of heads, the status of the repo, etc. For a great many things a command line and the way all the (text) utilities can be combined is much more powerful and versatile than what *any* GUI developer can come up with and it's exactly the same when working with (d)VCSes.

Then other developers on the same project prefer to use a Mercurial plugin for their IDE.

And then some other developers use both: GUI for some Mercurial things and command line for others.

I think that the really useful thing is to have the choice between both options, so that every developer can use what he's more familiar with and even both if he wishes to do so.